# matplotlib: how to make sizes of the subfigures without colorbars consistent with those with colorbars?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my figure composed of two subfigures below, one with colorbar and the other without colorbar.  Currently they are not of the same size due to the presence of the colorbar, I am wondering if there is a way to fix this?

[image]